# How to convert numerical portion of a string using regular expressions if the quantity is expressed as a range?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string containing a range of values in the form `"1-10uM Ach"` where 1 and 10 are not necessarily integers; they can be any floating number, `"uM"` stands for microMeter and then some irrelevant substring called `"Ach"`. Since each micro is `$10^{-6}$`, I would like to use regular expression to covert this string to another string of the form `"$10^{-6}-10^{-5}$"`. However, I am not sure what matching pattern I should use to isolate for numerical parts of the string to include *any possible floats before and after `"-"` symbol*.

Note:

1. The line always start with a range
2. There is always a unit after the range which can be any of the following values, mM, uM, nM, and pM which I know how to convert to M.
3. There could be a white space between last number and the unit.

Comment: Everything is the same except that my units can be anything in  mM, uM, nM, pM which I know how to convert to M. I just need to generalized the pattern r'^(.+?)-(.+?)\s*uM' such that any member of the set can be there and not just uM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to match explicitly on two ints or floats at the start of the line, separated by a `-`:

```
data = '2.345-4.321 uM'
vals = re.match(r'^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)', data)
print(vals[1], vals[2])
# 2.345 4.321
```

This regex will also match on numbers with a leading `.` but no `0` - e.g. `.456` - if you don't need this then you can remove `|\.[0-9]+` from each part.

Comment: I like this but I really want to get rid of uM in data pattern above as I have some missing units that I want to capture as well without touching them.

Comment: This pattern explicitly matches only the 2 numbers, so there can be anything non-numeric after the second number (spaces, letters etc) and they will be dropped, or nothing at all.

Comment: Just noticed that. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the 2 (float) numbers in 2 capture groups, and to match one of mM, uM, nM, pM you can use a character class.

```
^(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)[munp]M \S+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match a float like number being optional digits, optional dot and 1+ digits
- `-` Match a hyphen
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match another float like number
- `[munp]M` Match one of mM, uM, nM, pM
- `\S+` Match a space and 1 or more non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7qTR4/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)[munp]M \S+$"
s = "1-10uM Ach"
m = re.match(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

Output

```
1 10
```

Or for a partial match with word boundaries:

```
\b(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)[munp]M\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSTc6V/1)

If you are just interested in the numbers of the range of the pattern you can just use the first part:

```
^(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)
```

Comment: Thank you "The fourth bird". This is really elegant and I could have not known. But, I think you would agree with me that the other person needs more support :)

Comment: @Ash You are welcome. I am not sure what you mean by "needs more support". The pattern from the other answer is the same for the numbers, and a long notation of saying `^(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)` so if you want to match only those values you can use this shortened pattern.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ow yes, I see. Thanks for the heads up!